# Can we rename [redux] and [redux-framework] into [redux-js] and [redux-wordpress] tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

There is a lot of confusion between Redux (a new JavaScript library) and Redux Framework (a WordPress framework that has existed for 5+ years).

It is very inconveniencing for Redux Framework that people [started using its tag for Redux questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-framework). I think it would be great if we could rename [redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux) and [redux-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-framework) to [redux-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-js) and [redux-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-wordpress), respectively, to make the difference clearer.

Disclaimer: I’m author of Redux (the JS one).

Comment: Also, blacklist [redux], since it's bound to be recreated.